# How to get data of nearby attack to avoid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I want AI to avoid attack, but not sure how to get data. I made warning system that notice AI when warning_box and character collide. You may understand it by just looking picture below

[image]

Warning is deployed before attack starts. This is related code for Warning class

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    CharacterInteractor enemy = other.GetComponent<CharacterInteractor>();
    CharacterInteractor atker = attacker.GetComponent<CharacterInteractor>();

    if (enemy != null)
        // attacker and warned characters are different team
        if (attacker == null || enemy.team != atker.team)   
            enemy.Warn(this); 
}
private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    CharacterInteractor enemy = other.GetComponent<CharacterInteractor>();
    CharacterInteractor atker = attacker.GetComponent<CharacterInteractor>();

    if (enemy != null)
        if (attacker == null || enemy.team != atker.team)   // 상대가 적일 때
            enemy.WarnOff(this);
}
```

But only knowing what's just dangerous now is not enough. To find out best direction to avoid, AI need data of other warnings too. So I'm thinking of 2 styles, but both have problems.

## Tile system

[image]

Tile system use multiple colliders around character to find out contacted warnings. It's not good when safe position is placed between tiles.

## Radar system

[image]

Radar system use SphereCast() for multiple radius. I only can get how close warning is and where is center of it, unable to get direction to avoid. (maybe I don't know right Unity API)

I have no idea how to solve these problems. Is there any good way or example to solve problem?

Answer (score 1):

I discussed this problem with friends and get better idea than i asked.

to make better

1. tile system but use more smaller, many tiles.

to reduce cost

2. use 5m Sphere Cast to find out warnings. if find warnings, deploy tile system matrix.

Comment: Making smaller boxes solves your problem. I am not sure if you can sign your own answer as a solution but if you can you should.